# Mimic physical usb HID joystick input with Software GUI

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, gui, joystick

I have a program that takes input from a physical USB HID joystick controller. I want to create a software GUI that takes the place of that controller and have it operate identically (still send all it's inputs identically as if it was connected via USB). However I am confused by how to do that part. Where in Linux would I write the inputs of the software GUI to, in order to make it appear identical to the physical joystick?